# Set up ASP.NET MVC Identity authentication to create database and allow migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I can't seem to find an answer on which set of options belong together for managing my asp.net MVC identity database. I followed the book Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 Platform by Freeman to get it all set up. What it has you do is initially use a `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer for the `IdentityDbContext`. That drops and recreates the database any time you change the schema, which is fine for initial development of it.

Then in the next chapter he has you enable migration support with `Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations` and set up seeding an admin user in the `Configuration.Seed` method and change from the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer to a `NullDatabaseInitializer`. From that point on, when I made changes to properties in my user class, I just used the [`update-database` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to apply my model changes to the database until I got the schema the way I wanted it and then checked it all into source control.

Now I'm learning that after the other developers have gotten latest and run the application, the authentication database is not being created. Guess this makes sense since I'm now using a `NullDatabaseInitializer`. I tried setting that to a `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer but learned that causes the `Configuration.Seed` method not to run.

**So what do I need to do to allow migrations, in case we need to add more custom columns to our users/roles tables, etc., but also allow the database to be initially created and seeded if it does not exist?**

Here is my code that allows me to do migrations, but does not create the database for other developers:

```
public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AuthDbContext()
        : base("AuthDb", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
#if DEV
        Database.Log = sql => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sql);
#endif
    }

    static AuthDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AuthDbContext>(new IdentityDbInit());
    }

    public static AuthDbContext Create()
    {
        return new AuthDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityDbInit : NullDatabaseInitializer<AuthDbContext>
{
    //Database is seeded by MyNamespace.Web.Migrations.Configuration
}
```

Configuration.cs:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyNamespace.Web.Models.AuthDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        ContextKey = "MyNamespace.Web.Models.AuthDbContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyNamespace.Web.Models.AuthDbContext context)
    {
        //Seeding code omitted...

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing your initializer to [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_code_first_migration.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the article. That seems to be the best of all worlds. I can use automatic or code migrations and `update-database` explicitly in package manager or it will update at runtime when the database is actually accessed  (at first I thought it wasn't working, but I had to actually try to log in and access the database for it to update & call `Seed`). And most importantly it creates the database if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @SteveGreene Feel free to post that with a code example as the answer so I can mark it. Otherwise I will do it in a few days. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveGreene After upgrading to the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer, I've had a breakpoint set on my Configuration.Seed method and it seems to be called the first time the database is accessed every time the application starts, even if there are no migrations. Is this the expected behavior or have I configured something wrong?